# How to use is_unique except particular Row in codeigniter and MySQLi database

Tags: codeigniter

I want to update some data of my database before that  need to check whether that data available in other row except what i want to update.In that case how to use "is_unique".

Answer (score 0):

You would have to check on form submission, not during the update call. For example, if you're allowing the user to update their user name but want to make sure it isn't already taken, you could do something like the following:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('user_name', 'User Name', 'is_unique[users.user_name]');
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#rule-reference